# Atom Editor: Add dynamic menu items to command palette

Tags: view, package, atom-editor

I try to create a atom-editor package which provides its interface through the command palette.

I found the [SelectListView](https://atom.io/docs/api/v0.136.0/SelectListView) class which is exactly what I want but I can't find a documented way to append my own views to the command palette.

Is there a way to do that or is it simply not allowed?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you're trying to add your own commands to the Command Palette. Currently (as of v0.139.0), this is done through the `atom.workspaceView.command()` method:

```
atom.workspaceView.command 'package-name:command-name', ->
  # Code that you want to execute when the command is called
```

By convention, the name of all commands follows the pattern `package-name:command-name` so if your package was named "Foo Bar" and the command was "Frob The Fraggles" then the command name would be `foo-bar:frob-the-fraggles`.

The command system for packages is going to be updated in the near future, so you may want to watch the [Atom repository on GitHub](https://github.com/atom/atom) for updates. Even so, the above method should continue to work for a while after the change.